# how access ECC key in other file

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, public-key-encryption, ecdh

I  am using ECDH for encryption and decryption as in network i create 3 nodes sensor server and sink. i am encrypting data at sensor and want to decrypt it at server.
from tinyec import registry
import secrets

`    '# The elliptic curve which is used for the ECDH calculations
curve = registry.get_curve('brainpoolP256r1')

```
Ka = secrets.randbelow(curve.field.n)
X = Ka * curve.g 

Kb = secrets.randbelow(curve.field.n)
Y = Kb * curve.g 
print("Currently exchange the publickey (e.g. through Internet)")

A_SharedKey = Ka * Y
B_SharedKey = Kb * X``
```

i am using this code + encryption algorithm code in sensor.py file to encrypt data but at server file i am unable to decrypt data due to B_SharedKey i want to know that how can i access this B_SharedKey in server file from sensor file i try to send it to server file but output shows that i have to convert it into str and concatenate with other arguments but its not working as i passed it .... B_SharedKey type is point and how can i access it as it is in server file from sensor file

iam using this code + encryption algorithm code in sensor.py file to encrypt data but at server file i am unable to decrypt data due to B_SharedKey i want to know that how can i access this B_SharedKey in server file from sensor file i try to send it to server file but output shows that i have to convert it into str and concatenate with other arguments but its not working as i passed it .... B_SharedKey type is point and how can i acess it as it is in server file from sensor file in pycharm

Answer (score 0):

To answer exactly the question you've asked you could [serialise](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) or [jsonify](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) your Point object and reconstruct it at the server, however, this is **not at all secure** over an untrusted channel.

It looks like you are trying to roll your own crypto protocol with I *strongly* suggest you do not do. Instead use [existing verified protocols/libraries](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html) to manage a secure connection.